# unix dircmp is failing with the following error: sort: 0653-657 A write error occurred while merging

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to do a `dircmp -s dir1 dir2` on two very large directories. After waiting a good 15min, I get the following error:

```
sort: 0653-657 A write error occurred while merging.
```

I'm guessing it ran out of RAM while trying to execute the unix command. Do you guys have an alternative solution?

I can also code the solution in Perl if needed.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what the `dircmp -s` command does, and/or what your goal is.

Comment: And what is "very large" in numbers?

Comment: @TLP Essentially **dircmp** allows you to compare 2 directory tree structure and list all the **folders** that are the same or different. The **-s** flag suppresses the ones that are the same, therefore listing only the folders that are different.

Comment: Where is your temp directory?  Is it /tmp?  Does it fill up?  Do you have write access?

Comment: @mugenkenichi I just did a count, there's 800+ directories. As for the disk usage, about (200MB) and that includes the files that it contains.

Comment: @CraigTreptow Yes, it is at /tmp, I don't think it fills up and yes, I have write access.

Comment: I should have explained my thought process: dircmp, likely keeps two lists and sorts them so it can compare them easily.  I believe the sort command normally writes temp files to $TMPDIR (/tmp in your case).  So, doing a df and watching /tmp while dircmp runs would be worthwhile IMO.  To go with your initial thought on memory, you might also pull up top (or a similar tool) while the dircmp runs.

Comment: @CraigTreptow What should I do if I realize that **df tmp** changes because of the **dircmp** ?

Comment: I suspect it *will* change. The question is what do you do if it fills up.  If so, I guess your options are to make it bigger, use something else, or implement your own solution.

Comment: I'd like to use **dircmp** if possible, I'm already writing a script as an alternative solution, but I believe it might be cleaner to use **dircmp**

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, so I'm removing the "Perl" tag.

Answer (score 3):

If `sort` needs more memory than available*, it uses disk space. Specifically, the directory indicated by `-T`, `$TMPDIR` or `/tmp` (in descending order of precedence). My guess is that your temporary directory is filling up. If so, the solution would be to specify a work directory with more disk space.

* -- For some unknown and probably very loose definition of "available".

**Update**: hum, one little problem, you don't actually use `sort`. But it sounds like `dircmp` is spawning `sort`, in which case `sort` should inherit the `$TMPDIR` seen by `dircmp`.

Comment: unfortunately for me, I don't think I have the rights to modify the space availability for $TMPDIR. Does that mean that there's no way I can solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't say anything about changing the size of any drives?? I suggested that you use a different work directory.

Comment: in that case, I'm not sure what is $TMPDIR

Comment: An environment variable. If you use a sh-like shell, `export $TMPDIR=...`. Don't forget to make the directory.

Comment: nope didn't work, I still get that sort error. It's alright, I wrote my solution in Perl instead. I wonder if I have post my perl solution or close this thread :S